# Application not running in api level greater than 10

Tags: android

I am developing an android application that displays RSS feeds.
I am parsing and displaying the data.

My app is working fine in API level 10 but not working in API level 14.

in android Manifest file I set

> minSdkVersion="10" targetSdkVersion="19"

i am getting a blank screen in API level 14.

The following is displayed in Logcat

```
08-20 09:48:55.360: D/in create(1200): create
08-20 09:48:55.380: D/In main(1200): Main
08-20 09:48:55.770: D/gralloc_goldfish(1200): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-20 09:48:56.161: D/in background(1200): back
08-20 09:48:57.880: D/response code(1200): The response: 200
08-20 09:48:59.231: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 175K, 5% free 7094K/7431K, paused 10ms+12ms
08-20 09:49:06.071: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+7ms
08-20 09:49:11.121: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+28ms
08-20 09:49:16.810: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 14ms+13ms
08-20 09:49:21.800: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+7ms
08-20 09:49:26.770: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+8ms
08-20 09:49:31.670: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7090K/7687K, paused 10ms+8ms
08-20 09:49:36.570: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 10ms+10ms
08-20 09:49:41.480: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 12ms+7ms
08-20 09:49:46.380: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+7ms
08-20 09:49:51.430: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 12ms+7ms
08-20 09:49:56.470: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 13ms+7ms
08-20 09:50:01.760: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 7ms+10ms
08-20 09:50:06.941: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-20 09:50:12.570: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+8ms
08-20 09:50:18.360: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-20 09:50:24.000: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-20 09:50:29.600: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+8ms
08-20 09:50:35.081: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 7ms+8ms
08-20 09:50:40.340: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 10ms+8ms
08-20 09:50:45.871: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+9ms
08-20 09:50:51.081: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7090K/7687K, paused 15ms+7ms
08-20 09:50:56.700: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 11ms+9ms
08-20 09:51:02.780: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+9ms
08-20 09:51:08.450: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+8ms
08-20 09:51:13.570: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 15ms+15ms
08-20 09:51:20.280: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7090K/7687K, paused 7ms+16ms
08-20 09:51:25.760: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-20 09:51:30.710: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+9ms
08-20 09:51:35.710: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 13ms+9ms
08-20 09:51:40.780: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 13ms+10ms
08-20 09:51:45.680: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 12ms+7ms
08-20 09:51:50.380: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 10ms+7ms
08-20 09:51:55.140: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 7ms+10ms
08-20 09:51:59.980: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+10ms
08-20 09:52:04.951: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 7ms+11ms
08-20 09:52:09.851: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+9ms
08-20 09:52:14.761: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 12ms+7ms
08-20 09:52:19.940: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 14ms+8ms
08-20 09:52:24.991: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 10ms+8ms
08-20 09:52:30.211: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 14ms+8ms
08-20 09:52:36.480: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 17ms+9ms
08-20 09:52:42.821: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+8ms
08-20 09:52:48.530: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 10ms+7ms
08-20 09:52:53.570: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 10ms+8ms
08-20 09:52:58.570: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+8ms
08-20 09:53:03.861: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+8ms
08-20 09:53:08.901: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-20 09:53:13.991: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 13ms+7ms
08-20 09:53:19.680: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+7ms
08-20 09:53:24.660: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 7ms+7ms
08-20 09:53:29.520: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7090K/7687K, paused 9ms+12ms
08-20 09:53:34.981: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 7ms+8ms
08-20 09:53:39.861: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+15ms
08-20 09:53:44.670: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 11ms+7ms
08-20 09:53:49.991: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-20 09:53:54.891: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 7ms+8ms
08-20 09:53:59.791: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 8ms+10ms
08-20 09:54:04.901: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 10ms+7ms
08-20 09:54:10.400: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 12ms+9ms
08-20 09:54:15.370: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 10ms+7ms
08-20 09:54:20.170: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7090K/7687K, paused 14ms+11ms
08-20 09:54:25.651: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 7089K/7687K, paused 9ms+14ms
08-20 09:54:31.090: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7091K/7687K, paused 14ms+11ms
```

Comment: Look at the LogCat, it could probably tell you some valuable information - or copy-paste it into your question.

Comment: Also open your project.properties file. Maybe something's not updated (say, target = 10) inside it.

Comment: @Frank N.Stein their target=15

Comment: Usually the most likely reason for apps getting broken for api level >10 is NetworkOnMainThreadException but without any code, it's really impossible to say anything for sure.

Comment: @laalto i am not doing any n/w related operation in main thread.taken two separate thread for download and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably downloading and/or processing the RSS feed directly on the UI thread. Create a new thread and do that work inside that thread. Update the UI when the thread finishes.